# e.target.src only change to the first image

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have two sections, the first section has a couple of images and the second section has only one image and its display set as none.

On hover over those images, I want to change the src of the single image src put its only changing to the first image

Javascript:

```
 function gridHover() {
    const gridImages = document.querySelectorAll('.grid figure img');
    gridImages.forEach(function(picture){
        picture.addEventListener('mouseover', (e)=>{
            const thumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');
            thumbnails.style.display = 'block';
            thumbnails.src = e.target.src;
            console.log(e.target.src);
        })
    })
}
gridHover();
```

HTML

```
    <section class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-title">
            <h1>After August</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_01.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_02.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_03.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_04.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_05.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_06.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_07.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_08.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
            <article>
                <figure>
                    <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_09.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="thumbnails">
        <img src="../assets/media/images/after-august/after-august_01.jpg" alt="">
    </section>
```

Dunno whats wrong, my code seems fine. I tried to console.log(e.target.src) and it's giving me the actual images normally.

Comment: `thumbnails` refers to your `section` element - and a section element doesn’t have a `src` attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the img inside thumbnails class in const thumbnails variable.

```
function gridHover() {
        const gridImages = document.querySelectorAll('.grid figure img');
        gridImages.forEach(function(picture){
            picture.addEventListener('mouseover', (e)=>{
                const thumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails img');
                thumbnails.style.display = 'block';
                thumbnails.src = e.target.src;
                console.log(e.target.src);
            })
        })
    }
    gridHover();
```